# In magento get list of all attributes to create a new configurable product

Tags: magento-1.7

I would like to list all attributes checked as usable to create a configurable product. (such as the checkbox list just after choosing "create a configurable product".

I tried :

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getConfigurableId());`
```

But no collection is retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it works :

```
$product = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/product");
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
  if (($attribute->getIsConfigurable()) && ($attribute->getIsVisible()) && ($attribute->usesSource()) && ($attribute->getIsGlobal() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL)){
    ... do some things ...
  }
}
```

Perhaps not the best way to list these attributes !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute_collection');
```

Or if you want the configurable attributes assigned to a particular product:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute_collection')
    ->setProductFilter($product)
;
```